# Sitecore | Presentation details (renderings, layout settings etc) from one environment to other

Tags: sitecore

Presentation details (renderings, layout settings etc) from one environment (UAT env) is not copying to other environment (prelive env) when we create the package using Package Designer. When we install the package which is generated, on a prelive environment, all the presentation settings are getting lost including the layout details.

The templates are designed with standard values and items and pages are created using these templates. Everything looks fine but when we create the content and template package and install there won't be any presentation details including the layout out settings in the prelive environment. The only option left for us is to reset the standard values which we cannot every time when we move the content.

When we checked the xml inside the package layout setting values are null.

How can we move the contents from one environment to another? Is there any steps which are missing?

Need your help

Sitecore verions : Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 141226)

Answer (score 3):

Also, worth mentioning, if you just want to copy presentation details of an item, like layout, renderings, placeholders and assuming those do exist on target environment, you can do the following approach:

Ensure View tab has Standard fields checked and Raw values also checked.

[image]

Then, scroll down to Layouts section and expand it.

[image]

Rendering field contains all presentation details, serialized into XML. So now, if you copy them 'as-is' to clipboard and insert to another item - that item will immediately same layout, all renderings in the same order, placeholders etc. You may also copy that across environments, assuming both target and source environment have those layout and renderings.

More details on that can be found in the blog post: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/copying-presentation-details-manually

Comment: Martin, It's so helpful.Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue when the package is generated, so you may want to check the logs while you are creating the package, you should also make sure that you are including all the necessary items for layout in the package.

A more reliable solution might be to use serialization. You can serialize parts of your Sitecore tree to xml files on disk. You can then copy the serialized files on to the target environment and derserialize the xml back in to Sitecore items. (This is basically how Sitecore tools such as TDS and Unicorn run behind the scenes)

There's utilities in Sitecore to do this in the Content editor under the `Developer` tab called `Serialize Tree` and `Revert Tree`.

There's a post on this here:

http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2008/08/04/sitecore-6-serializating-items-and-whole-database-part-2/

Comment: Here is what sitecore says. "Please make sure that all related templates with their "__Standard Values" items are included in the package too."

Comment: Yes, good advice, when adding template items to the package I always include sub items so that standard values will get added as well

Answer (score 0):

Do the backward process, create a page with presentation layouts and so. on UAT create usual package and install it on DEV and check the output, if same issue is detected, you will need to install with overwrite your templates from main instances with standard values and everything on UAT or vice versa (depending on what instance content, layouts, devices, templates are correct). You might have a check on layouts and sublayouts differences between instances as well, maby somewone manualy modified a layout, delete/recreate/rename something on one of the instances.